# How to Append and batch process different logos with different images

Tags: image, image-processing, graphical-logo

I have list of images and logos and want to join them like appending it on middle while i have following details.

Images with name of files like image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg, image4.jpg all of them are in size of 1024x876

Logo with name of files like logo1.png, logo2.png, logo3.png and so on all of them are in size of 1024x876

I want to join image1.jpg with logo1.png, in a way that i should got the transparent image as logo image contain empty background.

Instead of copying every logo and pasting on every images, how can i do this automation with script or any paid tool. Tnx

Comment: Please provide `image1.jpg`, `logo1.png` and show how the result should look and what it should be called. Please also indicate if you are on Windows or a proper operating system.

Comment: Final img look like this. https://imgur.com/a/3wI1U and image1 look like this https://imgur.com/a/THlT7 and logo1 png look like this. https://imgur.com/a/tUswM i am using windows.

Answer (score 1):

I would commend **ImageMagick** to you, it is available for free for Linux, macOS and Windows. Use v7.

The basic command you want is:

```
magick -gravity center background.jpg overlay.png -composite result.jpg
```

[image]

If you have lots of files to do, you will need a [FOR](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) loop. I don't really speak Windows BATCH, but it will look something like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "usebackq" %%i in (`DIR /B *.jpg`) DO (
   ECHO magick -gravity center %%i %%~ni.png -composite result-%%i
)
```

Make a backup of your images and run this on a small sample copy. If it looks good, remove the `ECHO` and run again for real.